# How to serialize students with the (select-student) class condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am appending a class as selected and rejected to a student. Now I want to submit the form and I want to send all the students who have a of class `select-student`. This is my dynamic students code:

```
<form id="overideCommentForm" >
    <?php while($skillData = $skillQuery->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <td><span id="stu1" class="reject-student ">Not Selected</span></td>
        <td><span id="stu2" class="select-student ">Selected</span></td>
        <td><span id="stu5" class="select-student ">Selected</span></td>
        <td><span id="stu8" class="reject-student ">Not Selected</span></td>
        <td><span id="stu9" class="select-student ">Selected</span></td>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
<button id="gdFinal">Submit</button>
```

```js
$("#gdFinal").click(function(){
    var jobID = 50;
    $.ajax({
        url: "gdcontroller.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { 
            overideData : $("#overideCommentForm").serialize(), 
            'action': 'overrideStudent',
            'JobID': +jobID 
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
```

Comment: It's not cleat what you're trying to achieve here. What data do you want to send in the AJAX request? I assume the `id` of the `.select-student` elements, is that correct?

Comment: yes exactly she  wants to send student `id` who has the `select-student` class @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: yes i want to send `student id`who has the `select-student`

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send id of a particular class by using map function of jquery, so in the above code you can use the following to send selected and rejected users as follows

```
var selected = $(".select-student").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
var reject = $(".reject-student").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
$("#gdFinal").click(function() {
    var jobID = 50;
    $.ajax({
        url: "gdcontroller.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            overideData: $("#overideCommentForm").serialize(),
            'action': 'overrideStudent',
            'JobID': +jobID,
            selected: selected,
            reject: reject
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to send student id who has the select-student

If that's your aim, you can use `map()` to build an array of the `id` attributes of the elements with the given class. Try this:

```
$("#gdFinal").click(function(){
    var jobID = 50;
    var studentIds = $('.select-student').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        url: "gdcontroller.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { 
            overideData : $("#overideCommentForm").serialize(), 
            action: 'overrideStudent',
            JobID: jobID,
            students: studentIds // used here
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {                
            // your logic here...
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To send the `id` of the students with class `select-student` then use:

```js
var ids = [];
$("#overideCommentForm span.select-student").each(function() { // overired form is id
  ids.push(this.id);
});
```

Use this in your click handler and pass this in ajax data.